# How can I DM someone who has a mutual server with my bot using my .dm command, if possible? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When people want to give feedback about the bot using my feedback command, I want to be able to dm them back through the bot, but my DM command doesn't work, even if they have a mutual server with the bot. When I run that command, I get this error: `/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.fetch_user' was never awaited`. Can anyone help me with this? Here's my code:

```
@client.command(description="This command DMs people and can only be used by the owner.")
@commands.is_owner()
async def dm(ctx, id, *, message):
    user = await client.fetch_user(id)
    await user.send(message)
    return
```

Comment: As the error said, you're supposed to await `client.fetch_user` since it's a coroutine

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now. I'll fix that. I'm still new to dpy, that's why I mess up on silly things sometimes

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I did that, but the bot still can only dm people in the server that the command was run. Do you know why?

Comment: I don’t really understand, mind rephrasing?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(description="This command DMs people and can only be used by the owner.")
@commands.is_owner()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.send("Mention the user or provide user id of the user you want me to send a DM to.")

    else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Sure, What do you want me to send to {member.display_name} ?", description="write anything here")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        def check(m):
            return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
        message = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(f'Message sent to {member.display_name}!')
    
        await member.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Sent a message - \n{message.content}")
```

Comment: Hey there Taufeeq! Instead of just pasting a large code segment, add comments using `#` or add a description so we know what you're doing. Robert may not know how `wait_for` works, or may not know what does what, so it would be best if you explained it as best as you could. Happy coding, and make edits where you can!

Comment: Hey Bagle, Thank you for the advice :D I'll make sure to explain instead of just giving code. I just wanted to help by giving the code from my bot. But I'll make sure to explain it next time :D. Thank you and have a great day!